# Export Google Cloud Datastore and import to BigQuery programmatically

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

I'm looking for a method to export my Cloud Datastore and import it into BigQuery daily. The manual way is described at [google page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-cloud-datastore). I do not find a clean way to automate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to do this, but you can separate out the two parts: creating appengine backups and loading them into bigquery.

You can use scheduled backups to create datastore backups periodically (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups).

You can then use Apps Script to automate the BigQuery portion (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#load_csv_data) or use an AppEngine cron to do the same thing.

Comment: The second like is to load to BigQuery with a Google Drive. It's possible to use it with Google Cloud Storage Directly? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am working on rewrite the apps script but I have a doubt. The [exemple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#load_csv_data) use 'job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId, data); ' and in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/Bigquery.Jobs.Insert.html#Bigquery.Jobs.Insert%28java.lang.String,%20com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.Job,%20com.google.api.client.http.AbstractInputStreamContent%29) is 'job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(projectId, job, data); '.

Answer (score 4):

As of last week there's a proper way to automate this. The most important part is `gcloud beta datastore export`.

I created a script around it: https://github.com/chees/datastore2bigquery
You could run this in a cron job.

See here for a demo of how it works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGyQCE3bWkU

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Jordan's answer above, the steps to do this would be:

1) Make a storage bucket

2) Export datastore entities to this bucket

3) Open Big Query Web UI, and load using the Google Cloud file path.

Full tutorial with images is available at [this post](http://www.smartgooglecloud.com/gcs/bigquery/datastore-export-to-bigquery-part-1-manual-export/).

Answer (score -1):

It is possible using the following code. It basically uses App Engine Cron jobs and BigQuery API.

https://github.com/wenzhe/appengine_datastore_bigquery